# MYSQL and PHPMYADMIN cant connect via php

Tags: php, mysql

Ive set up phpmyadmin and mySql on my windows server but when i try to connect via php i get this error :

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\newservertest\dbscripts\sqlconnection.php on line 5

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=15852 in C:\xampp\htdocs\newservertest\dbscripts\sqlconnection.php on line 5

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\newservertest\dbscripts\sqlconnection.php on line 5

Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\newservertest\dbscripts\sqlconnection.php on line 14
```

I know by default mySql only allows local connections but following tutorials online they are all saying to uncomment a line in a "my.ini" file. All i have in my sql folder is a my-default.ini with the following :

[image]

How can i open this up to connections from an external php script?

Comment: this has nothing to do with phpmyadmin, phpmyadmin is just a interface for the mysql database.

Comment: If the script is external you need to open up the MySQL port 3306 (TCP) in your router and forward it to your machine. Make sure to also open up the port in your firewall. Furthermore you'll need to add a user that has the proper hostname set.

Comment: It is open i can access php myadmin externally from outside the network using serverip:pornum/phpmyadmin -- i just cant use php scripts

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your php.ini:

```
mysqli.reconnect = 1
```